# Why is this css selector for ::selection not working?

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to give the p tag selection styles, but it doesn't work, any idea why?

```
body.blog p::selection,
body.blog p::-moz-selection {
 color: red;
}
```

```
<body class="blog">
<p class="text-condensed-light text-15-rem mt-20">This text should be red when selected.</p>
</body>
```

Any help appreciated.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/cowall/pen/ExEBzwa)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. You can use `Stack Snippets`.

Comment: it works on firefox if you modify the rule using just `body.blog p::selection` as selector

Comment: Not on chrome though....

Comment: here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection it says it works everywhere (latest versions) except safari on ios

Comment: Fixed your issue. Kindly experiment first before posting. You can just remove moz prefix. (https://codepen.io/susanta96/pen/GRxbaMM)

Comment: @susanta96 oh I experimented, would have never thought that that is the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a browser encounters a selector it does not support it ignores the *whole* rule.

So separate the rules.

```css
p::-moz-selection {
  color: red;
}

p::selection {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="text-condensed-light text-15-rem mt-20">This text should be red when selected.</p>
```